# Can't get Django to send me debug mail

Tags: django, email, heroku

I have a Django site that I have deployed to Heroku, and I'm having trouble getting it to send me error notifications via email. I've logged into the Heroku console and used `django.core.mail.send_mail()` to send emails, so I know it's configured to send correctly.

I've got `ADMINS` and `MANAGERS` configured, and the `django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware` Middleware so I should be getting emails whenever someone gets a 404 error on the page. I have the following Logging configuration in my `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': False,
            'formatters': {
                'verbose': {
                    'format': ('%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] ' +
                               'pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s ' +
                               'funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s'),
                    'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
                },
                'simple': {
                    'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
                }
            },
            'handlers': {
                'mail_admins': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                    'include_html': True,
                },
                'null': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
                },
                'console': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                    'formatter': 'verbose'
                }
            },
            'loggers': {
                'testlogger': {
                    'handlers': ['console'],
                    'level': 'INFO',
                }
            }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Just to cover all bases, is `DEBUG` False in the settings?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yep. When I get a 404, it's just a regular 404, not the `DEBUG=True` 404 page.